# Cómo mostrar elementos de diferentes models en una lista con angular

Tags: angular

Quiero mostrar en una lista en html datos de dos diferentes models pero no sé cómo llamar desde html, al inicio utilicé `*ngFor` pero se me repiten los datos. A continuación dejo mi código.

Mi primera clase a la que llamo es esta:

```
  export class Usuario {

        ci!:string;
        nombres!:string;
        apellidos!:string;
        telefono!:string; 
     }
```

y mi segunda clase es esta:

```
  export class Cuenta {

        idCuenta!:number;
        email!:string;
     }
```

ahora lo que quiero es que estos datos se impriman en una solo lista en `html`.

Este es mi usuario component:

```
   @Component({

       selector: 'app-usuarios',
       templateUrl: './usuarios.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./usuarios.component.css']

   })

export class UsuariosComponent implements OnInit {

      cuentas!:Cuenta[];
      roles!:Rol[];
      users!:Usuario[];

  constructor(private cuentaService:CuentaService,private rolService:ROLService,private userService:UsuarioService) { }

     ngOnInit() {

          this.cuentaService.getAll().subscribe(
          c =>this.cuentas=c
      );


        this.rolService.getAllid().subscribe(
          r =>this.roles=r
     );

       this.userService.getAllus().subscribe(
          u =>this.users=u

       );

  }
}
```

y este es mi html:

```
             <tr *ngFor="let us of users">
                  
                  <th *ngFor="let cuent of cuentas" scope="row">{{cuent.idCuenta}}</th>
                  <td >{{us.ci}}</td>
                  <td >{{us.nombres}}</td>
                  <td >{{us.apellidos}}</td>
                  <td *ngFor="let cuent of cuentas">{{cuent.email}}</td>
                  <td >{{us.telefono}}</td>
                  <td *ngFor="let ro of roles">{{ro.nombre}}</td>
              </tr>
```

Así queda con el id y lo mismo con el email: se repiten los datos

```
id    nombre    apellido   email 
 
1     2        pedro       mora    a@hotmail.com b@hotmail.com 

1     2        sara        sanchez a@hotmail.com b@hotmail.com
```

lo cual hace que en mi tabla se repitan los datos de `scope="row"` y el email, no sé si habrá otra forma de llamar el email y el id de cuenta para no utilizar el *nFor porque creo que eso le hace que se repitan los datos.

Comment: Hace que se repita... no, la que hace que se repita eres tú. Si usas dos loops for para iterar sobre cuentas (dos veces haces `*ngFor="let cuent of cuentas"`, cómo esperas que no se repitan?? Por qué usas ese segundo ngFor? Si ya estás dentro del primero... no te hace falta ese `*ngFor`, simplemente pon `cuent.email` y ya está

Comment: si, lo que pasa es que cuent pertenece a otra clase si le quito *ngFor="let cuent of cuentas" me sale este error Property 'cuent' does not exist on type 'UsuariosComponent'.ngtsc(2339)
usuarios.component.ts(26, 22): Error occurs in the template of component UsuariosComponent.

Comment: en el usuario component esta declarado  cuentas!:Cuenta[];
  users!:Usuario[];

Comment: Entonces lo que está mal es tu modelo de datos. Si cada usuario tiene una cuenta nada más, lo correcto es que tengas un objeto wrapper *"envolviendo"* tu objeto usuario y cuenta, no que tengas arrays separados y reces para que vengan ordenados igual. Tu html no tiene ningún error, hace lo que le pides... simplemente le estás pidiendo que haga algo incorrecto porque tu modelo de datos no es correcto ni consistente. `cuenta` es algo propiedad del `usuario` tal como lo estás pintando, sin embargo tienes un array de ellas para un único usuario? No tiene sentido.

Comment: En resumen, si no quieres que se repitan, no iteres sobre ellos. Si puedes modificar el backend para que devuelva un único objeto en vez de una lista, hazlo. Si no... pues no sé, hardcodea el acceso a la lista de cuentas por ejemplo: `<td>{{cuentas[0].email}}</td>`. De todas maneras, como ya he dicho, si es la cuenta de un determinado usuario no tiene sentido que tengas un array de ellas... debería ser un único objeto, no un array

Comment: listo, muchas gracias, es verdad que el modelo estaba mal, no hacia q Cuenta contuviera a usuarios